# Django model default sort order using related table field

Tags: django, django-models

Is it possible to set the default sort order for a model to a field from a related model (rather than the integer key) i.e. something that yields a SQL order by clause with a field from both models? If so, how? I can do this via query_by but I can't figure out how to set it by default. Thanks.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Bar(models.Model):
    related = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    bar_date = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('bar_date', 'related.name', )
```

Answer (score 39):

I use django 1.2.7 and instead of connecting ForeignKey.Attribute we should use "__", so this code will work:

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ('bar_date', 'related__name', )
```

Comment: If you need to sort by only one column and you get the error:
`'ordering' must be a tuple or list (even if you want to order by only one field).`
just replace `(...)` with `[...]`

Comment: @donnadulcinea You can also create a single-item tuple by adding a comma after the first item, e.g. `('bar_date',)`

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at [order-with-respect-to](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#order-with-respect-to).

Comment: This is important since it's 2021 and we're at Django 3.2. Many answers on SO are so darn old, that it's worth mentioning that this answer still holds up even now.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to order_with_respect_to (which only supports one field), you can use a custom manager to provide the ordering. This also allows you to order on multiple fields in Foo and to still have a normal Bar.objects manager. You'll have to test to see if the Meta.ordering or the custom manager ordering is applied first.

```
class FooSortedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(FooSortedManager, self).get_query_set().order_by('foo__name')

class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Bar(models.Model):
    related = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    bar_date = models.DateField()

    foo_sorted = FooSortedManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('bar_date',)
```

Answer (score 4):

In modern version of django it is:

```
class Meta:
        ordering = ['word']
```

Comment: This answer is unhelpful, as it doesn't use the actual wording from the question so it's unclear how it's different in recent versions.

Answer (score 0):

hmm ... I am solving similar thing while upfactoring old django application, written before qs-rf, where "dot" notation was probably used ??? ... it took me few hours to diclose "something" and I am still NOT sure, but ... try to replace dot with "__" (double underscores), this can help, .. In fact, curentlly, I still HOPE TOO :-)))

@stuart: for "order_with_respect_to", I readed something about automatically added physical model field into child table ... I dont completelly understand how things are here ... IMHO documentation is very bad about ordering syntax, howgh!

no comment :-)
http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8975

anyway, I like Django, yet ... :-))

Answer (score -2):

```
class Question(models.Model):

  question_text=models.CharField(max_length=200)
        class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural="  Question"

class Choice(models.Model):

  question=models.ForeignKey(Question,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural=" Choice"
```

Either you can alter the number of spaces before the class name as above or order it using numbers as below:

```
class Question(models.Model):

  question_text=models.CharField(max_length=200)
        class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural="1.Question"

class Choice(models.Model):

  question=models.ForeignKey(Question,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural="2.Choice"
```