# Unable to group sum value in Django query

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have a Django model that looks like this (I've trimmed a few details for brevity):

```
class Resource(models.Model):
    role = models.ForeignKey('Role')
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project')
    start_date = models.DateField
    percentage = models.DecimalField
```

I've got a bunch of rows in this table with various `percentage` values, and I want to sum them up for each unique `start_date`. In playing in the database by hand, I found that the SQL to do this is:

```
SELECT start_date, SUM(percentage) AS "total"
FROM myapp_Resource
GROUP BY start_date
```

When I try to use the Django machinery to get a similar query, I inevitably get the wrong thing. I would think that the following code would give me what I want:

```
Resource.objects.values('start_date').annotate(total = Sum('percentage'))
```

Unfortunately, it returns the following query:

```
SELECT start_date, SUM(percentage) AS "total"
FROM myapp_resource
INNER JOIN myapp_role ON ( myapp_resource.role_id = myapp_role.id )
GROUP BY start_date, myapp_role.name
ORDER BY myapp_role.name ASC
```

Where is this inner join coming in? Nowhere am I explicitly indicating that there's a join; I'm not even interested in that column! Are my ForeignKeys biting me somehow? I've tried variations of [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#annotate), but to no avail. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it's the order by part that is causing the inner join... you need to track down what is causing that clause to get added

Comment: do you have something like this in `Resource.Meta` http://stackoverflow.com/a/7497149/202168 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear any ordering in the query explicitly:

```
Resource.objects.values('start_date').annotate(total=Sum('percentage')).order_by()
```

Please see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by) for more info on the interference of the default ordering (as mentioned in the comment you got above from @Anentropic)

Comment: That was it! I didn't realize the default ordering was what was biting me. Thanks for the tip!